# addEventListener on form submit

Tags: javascript, dom-events

This is what I have and it's not working.

```
document.getElementById('form1').addEventListener('submit', function(){
    document.getElementById('donate').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('topMessage').style.display = 'none';
});
```

The JavaScript console shows this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: Where are you trying to set the onclick property ?

Comment: That error doesn't seem to be related to the posted code ?

Comment: take another look at your console, along with that error should be the line number of your script which is actually causing the error, post the code that is at that line, and the associated html.

Comment: Many thanks for all the suggestions. I went back to my code and forgot that I already have an existing javascript somewhere in the page. I deleted that and now I do not receive any errors but after the form has been submitted, the two divs that I'm trying to hide did not work. Those two divs are still showing on the page.

Comment: Okay, so if I use the code below, which is onclick, it works but with an error.

Comment: document.getElementById('form1').PC2095_btnNext.onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById('donate').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('topMessage').style.display = 'none';
};

Comment: Okay here's the related HTML code below. The event listener works because I put in an alert to test it out and it does popup an alert when I clicked on the submit button. The display= 'none' works when I execute it in the Firefox Javascript console. However, when I put all of these together, it does not work.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. All I need the preventDefault(); So, here's the solution.

```
document.getElementById('form1').addEventListener('submit', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('donate').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('topMessage').style.display = 'none';
})
```